# Custom query in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an integer field in a table.

I want to read the first digit of this field, then up to that digit read next digits.

For example consider this field: **355560**

- I read the first digit (3)
- Then read 3 digits after 3 : (555)

How would I write my select query?

Comment: Why do you need a stored procedure? (PL/SQL is ***only*** for stored procedures - and  you specifically asked for PL/SQL)

Comment: Use "substring" (substr) or one of the left/right functions?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : I dont want use sp! can I write in a simple select query??

Comment: Yes, but then it's not `PL/SQL` it's plain `SQL`

Comment: @AndyThompson : can I use substr ? how can I write the select query with substr?   select substr(<myField>,?,?) from <myTable>

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : OK. forget PL-SQL . how can I write that in SQL ?

Comment: What do you need to do with these extracted parts of the field?

Comment: @peterm : why you ask this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTR (355560, 2, SUBSTR (355560, 1, 1))
  FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Then replace the number in this query with the `column name` and dual with `table name`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select substr('355560', 2, substr('355560', 0, 1)) from dual
```

Comment: just exchange "355560" with columnname?

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
SELECT SUBSTR(355560,1,1) FROM DUAL

OUTPUT : 3

SELECT SUBSTR(355560,2,3) FROM DUAL

OUTPUT : 555
```

Comment: thanks but I want to use in general case! not just for this example. I mean I have a lot of fields, that I want use my query on them!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question:

```
select concat(substr(35550,1,1),substr(35550,2,3)) from dual
```

Comment: thanks but I want to use in general case! not just for this example. I mean I have a lot of fields, that I want use my query on them!